# Scheduling .jar file with Windows Scheduler

Tags: java, batch-file, jar, scheduled-tasks

I'm trying to schedule a .jar but nothing happens when I execute the task.
I had done this before so I know it can be done but I don't seem to configure my task properly.
I've already tried a bunch of configurations for my task so I will just mention the most relevant ones:
Task Scheduler->Create new basic task->Set trigger to when a user Logs in:

Program/script:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\bin\java.exe"
```

Arguments:

```
-jar C:/Users/Username/Documents/myJar.jar
```

Also tried with

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\bin\javaw.exe
```

and

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\java.exe
```

and

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe
```

I also tried creating a batch file which contains the following line:

```
java -Xmx1024m -jar C:/Users/Username/Documents/myJar.jar
```

It doesn't work if I click it or if I schedule it or Run As Admin.
All the tasks above are scheduled with highest privileges.

However if I Run cmd As Admin and execute :

```
java -Xmx1024m -jar C:/Users/Noctis/Documents/WallpaperChanger.jar
```

It works. I would appreciate any help. thanks in advance.

Comment: do you want to run this jar in background like service ?

Comment: I just want it launched. I don't know what it means to run as a service. When it's launched I should see java.exe or javaw.exe in the processes. It does work when I run it through cmd. But not otherwise.

Comment: ok, If you want to schedule it, you are right. Service is like start once and run all the time. Here just u try with `java -Xmx1024m -jar C:/Users/Username/Documents/myJar.jar` in Program/script and leave arguments blank

Comment: It doesn't really matter if it's a service or not as long as I get to launch it. I tried what you suggested and Script only takes a file path and it automatically puts the arguments in the arguments text box.

Comment: oh ok. I've worked jar with linux corn jobs, no issues there. what is your OS ? I can also try

Comment: Im running Windows 7 64bit. And thanks for your help.